# Error "The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded"

Tags: c#, cmd.exe

I have a trouble when run win 10

"**The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded**"

I tried the way, but not working
And now, My PC just working in command promt
Safemode not working with my trouble
And some file on ProfileList ( Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList) have lost

Could someone please help me this my trouble.
Thank you so much !

Comment: How did it get into this state?
Are you certain safe mode cannot be started with Shift+F8?
Have you tried a recovery drive/disc or startup repair?

Comment: I think Profile account had deleted not right

Comment: You deleted your profile and now cannot log in to it? Is that what is happening?

Comment: yes, i think so. It have deleted not right, and now i cann't log in profile win 10. And screen always display "The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user profiles got corrupted somehow.

Restarting into safemode can be done with holding Shift+F8
If this does not even load, you might have to try a recovery disc or reinstall the OS. If I recall there were some options to repair startup of a Windows 10 install from one of the advanced menus in the installer or from a recovery flash drive.

Sometimes the ProfileList in the registry retains backup versions that can be edited in a safe mode or recovery mode and renamed to load it up.

Where you can find ones with the same prefix as the .bak entry and rename them to switch it around.
Then edit the State REG_DWORD in the baked up record you just renamed and set it to 0
Also Refcount modify to 0

Or creating a new user if possible.

Recommend to make a registry backup by exporting these first before you tamper with them.

See: https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/fix-user-profile-service-failed-the-sign-in.html

Or: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyuPbd02m4Y

Of course that assumes you can get into a safe mode.
Starting from last known good configuration might also help.

https://www.lifewire.com/fix-a-computer-that-always-stops-at-startup-settings-or-abo-2624445

Comment: I think Profile account had deleted not right. I was got in safe mode, but safe mode not this problems solving and I tried starup repair, but It didn't good working . I do not recovery drive/disc, because My PC have some file important and when It just worked in my PC

Comment: in current, my pc just operate command promt,I follow your instruction, but some file ( Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ S-1-5-21-2803283244-2204869668-4256454697-1001) have lost, then i don't know how to fix